# How to add new field on array item

Tags: mongodb

I have the following json structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5203af83396d285ea2ecff8f"),
  "brand" : "LG",
  "comments" : [{
      "user_id" : ObjectId("521b2785eda03d0f9cab3566"),
      "text" : "Nice TV"
    }],
  "model" : "47LS5600",
  "price" : 499.0,
  "thumbnail" : "lg-47LS5600"
}
```

I need to insert a new field "datetime" in the array "comments" like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5203af83396d285ea2ecff8f"),
  "brand" : "LG",
  "comments" : [{
      "user_id" : ObjectId("521b2785eda03d0f9cab3566"),
      "text" : "Nice TV",
      "datetime": <value>
    }],
  "model" : "47LS5600",
  "price" : 499.0,
  "thumbnail" : "lg-47LS5600"
}
```

I tried with bellow instruction:

```
db.tvs.update({ _id: ObjectId("5203af83396d285ea2ecff8f") }, { $addToSet: { "comments.1": { "datetime": Date() } } } )
```

But it doesn´t inserts the field in the item, it creates another object separate from that item

Comment: This could help you: `db.tvs.update({ _id: ObjectId("5203af83396d285ea2ecff8f") }, { $set: { "comments.0.datetime": Date() } } )`. And RTFM ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator

Modify Documents: [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/)

Check Out this Code.

```
db.bios.update(
   { _id: 3 },
   { $set: {
             mbranch: 'Navy',
             'name.aka': 'Amazing Grace'
           }
   }
)
```